# Sybase LIST function truncating results after 256 characters

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, sybase

I'm trying to aggregate a column of strings into one cell by concatenating them together and separating them with commas using syabase's LIST fuction. But the results get truncated after 256 characters. Does anyone know of a way to fix this or if there are any alternatives that would give me what I'm looking for.

For example, if I have a table `myTable` that looks like this:

```
myVal
-------------
'0000000001'
'0000000002'
'0000000003'
'0000000004'
'0000000005'
'0000000006'
'0000000007'
'0000000008'
'0000000009'
'0000000010'
'0000000011'
'0000000012'
'0000000013'
'0000000014'
'0000000015'
'0000000016'
'0000000017'
'0000000018'
'0000000019'
'0000000020'
'0000000021'
'0000000022'
'0000000023'
'0000000024'
'0000000025'
'0000000026'
'0000000027'
'0000000028'
'0000000029'
'0000000030'
```

then run the following query:

```
select list(myVal,',') as myResult from myTable
```

I get the following result

```
myResult
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000001,0000000002,0000000003,0000000004,0000000005,0000000006,0000000007,0000000008,0000000009,0000000010,0000000011,0000000012,0000000013,0000000014,0000000015,0000000016,0000000017,0000000018,0000000019,0000000020,0000000021,0000000022,0000000023,000
```

Notice the result string gets truncated after `0000000023`

Comment: It's probably using an implicit `nvarchar(256)` type, hence the limit. What happens if you cast to `ntext` or `nvarchar(max)` first?

Comment: Both worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    LIST( CAST( myVal AS nvarchar(max) ), ',' )
FROM
    myTable
```